# Как выделить память под случайный массив Си?

Tags: c, массивы

Задача такая,нужно создать случайный массив с выделением памяти,но я не имею малейшего понятия как это сделать.Ранее пытался просто добавить переменную MEM к функции rand(),но это не дало результата.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int MemoryAccess(int I,int J){
   int *MEM;
   MEM = (int*)calloc((I*J),sizeof(int));
   int A[I][J];
 
    for(int i=0;i<I;i++){ 
 
    printf("\n"); 
 
        for(int j=0;j<J;j++){ 
 
            A[i][j]= rand()%2; 
 
        } 
 
    }
    for(int i=0;i<I;i++){ 
 
     printf("\n"); 
 
        for(int j=0;j<J;j++){
          printf("%d",A[i][j]);

}
      }
  }

int main() {
    int I=5,J=15,*P;
    P = MemoryAccess(I,J);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str = malloc(CAPACITY);
```

можете наставить CAPACITY так, сколько вам нужно памяти, например   `#define CAPACITY 20` вначале программы. Каждый раз, когда не будет хватать, можете использовать realloc(str, CAPACITY*2) например. Не забудьте в конце освободить память через free(str)